# Changing the tick time in FreeRTOS

Tags: programming, arduino-ide

I am trying to use FreeRTOS's vTaskDelay() function in order to periodically execute tasks.  The latest version of FreeRTOS came with the "tick" time set to 15 ms. Therefore, the smallest resolution I can delay for is 15 ms. I would like to lower this resolution to at least 1 ms.  Is it possible to configure FreeRTOS in this way?  I found this answer online : http://www.freertos.org/FreeRTOS_Support_Forum_Archive/November_2012/freertos_Problem_changing_Tick_time_from_1ms_to_10ms_6231539.html.

But for me, the configTICK_RATE_HZ is not defined and it seems to be using a watchdog timer to enforce the 15 ms resolution. I think the forums are referring to an earlier version.

Comment: see [also](https://github.com/AndreiCherniaev/FreeRTOS_ATmega2560_MPLAB) this FreeRTOS port with F_CPU

Answer (score 2):

See the [configTICK_RATE_HZ](http://www.freertos.org/a00110.html#configTICK_RATE_HZ) configuration option.
Also note it is better to specify times in milliseconds, rather than ticks, so you can change the tick frequency without effecting the timing (other than the resolution of the time).

The `pdMS_TO_TICKS()` macro can be used for that purpose, for example to create a delay of 100ms.

```
const TickType_t xBlockTime = pdMS_TO_TICKS( 100 );
vTaskDelay( xBlockTime );
```